# What is the probability density function (pdf) of the dot product of M complex normal random variables?

Tags: probability-distributions

What would be the probability density function (pdf) of the complex random variable given below?

$$Z = \sum_{i=1}^{M}{x_{i}^{*}y_{i}}$$

where $x_i, y_i$ are independent r.v.'s with $\mathcal{CN}(0,c)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The joint characteristic function $\Psi(\omega_1,\omega_2)$ of the real and imaginary parts of $Z=z_1+iz_2$ is derived in: [Distribution of Inner Product of Complex Gaussian Random Vectors and its Applications](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6047542/) (2011). That publication is behind a pay wall. You can find the expression in equation 14 of this [paper](http://hosting.uop.gr/~nsagias/images/articles/J1_2014.pdf), for the most general case that each $x_i$ and $y_i$ can have different Gaussian distributions. For the case in the OP the characteristic function is simply $\Psi(\omega_1,\omega_2)=[1+\tfrac{1}{4}c^2(\omega_1^2+\omega_2^2)]^{-M}$.

Comment: What does OP stand for?

Comment: https://www.lifewire.com/what-does-o-p-stand-for-2483372